# How to add description field from sales.order order_line to stock.picking pack_operation_product_ids?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10

How to pass data from `order_line` (`description_picking`) to `stock.picking pack_operation_product_ids` ? I'm confused ,I have already searched some answer but no one solve my problem. Thanks you

Comment: invoice object has relation to sale/purchase order (using their line object, i.e. purchase.order.line, sale.order.line, and account.invoice.line). also, object stock.picking has relation to sale/purchase order. So you can connect those objects to get connection from invoice_line_ids to pack_operation_ids.

Comment: @Al Imran
Sorry , i mean not invoice_line_ids but sale_order_line .